# RSpec Test Call to ActiveMailer model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, tdd, rspec

Hey everyone I am trying to get Rspec to test if an action calls a specific method in a model I have which inherits from ActiveMailer but have been having no luck.  So as a quick mockup I have the following scenario.  Model UserNotifier:

```
class UserNotifier < ActionMailer::Base  
  def foobaz
  end
end
```

Controller Password Controller:

```
class PasswordsController < ApplicationController

def foobar
  UserNotifier.foobaz
end
```

And the spec:

```
 describe "GET 'foobar'" do

   it "should call the UserNotifier foobaz method" do
     UserNotifier.should_receive(:foobaz)
     get :foobar
   end
 end
```

but I always end up with this failure:

```
1) PasswordsController GET 'foobar' should call the UserNotifier foobaz method
 Failure/Error: UserNotifier.should_receive(:foobaz)
   (<UserNotifier (class)>).foobaz(any args)
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to why RSpec does not register that the UserNotifier.foobaz method is being called?

Comment: I duplicated this and the example passes. Maybe you should post the original code where you found the problem.

Comment: this is the original code - i didnt change a thing and cannot get this to pass.

Comment: I think it's not getting to `PasswordsController` because you've got some sort of login check there or in one of its super controllers.

Comment: ugh thanks ryan had a before filter in the controller that was preventing the action from being run.  there goes a couple hours down the drain :-(.  ha be sure to leave an answer and i will mark it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in the comments by Ryan Bigg.  Ended up being a before_filter which was causing the method to never be run

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem, but it's not due to any filters (not using any). One difference is that I'm calling an action on ApplicationController, though I don't see why that would matter. The foobaz method definitely gets called, given that the rspec run includes output I insert there, yet Rspec doesn't see the call. Any other ideas for what could be wrong?

Comment: nevermind; i tried various mocks to catch the call while sorting this out, and they were failing; the equivalent to UserNotifier.should_receive(:foobaz) works now